# How to run a command ( ifup eth0 ) 10 seconds AFTER the desktop loads?

Tags: linux, centos

My modem does not connect as fast to the internet as the computer reboots. My modem and my computer are connected to the same outlet that I shut off and on via remote, so I need the computer to wait at least 10 seconds before running

```
ifup eth0
```

Currently I have `ifup eth0` in

```
 /etc/rc.local
```

but it is simply too fast, and if I add `sleep 10` to this file, it probably would hang up and wait 10 seconds before it loads the desktop.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The most portable way (not knowing what shell runs your /etc/rc.local) would be to add

```
$SHELL -c "sleep 10; ifup eth0" &
```

to your rc.local. This will run a sub-shell in the background (`&`) which runs the two command mini-script without stalling rc.local.

Answer (score 7):

Since this is CentOS, the most appropriate thing to do would be to add `LINKDELAY=10` (or longer) to your /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth0 file.  The documentation for this file is in /usr/share/doc/initscripts-9.03.38/sysconfig.txt.